# Banner images redirect to pages other than defined in href

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

Here is my page:http://www.candoor.ca/index-1.html The slider I used is slippry slider. If I click on banner images it will load about us page. While there is separate page defined in HREF="" for each slide.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is because all the `li`'s of your `<ul id="slippry-demo" />` are positioned `absolute` and all have a `z-index:2;`. Since your last slide is the link to the about page it is always on top and that is the one you click.

You don't notice this because only the `li` with the class `sy-active` has an `opacity:1;`, all other `li`'s have `opacity:0;`.

Comment: Create a style for `sy-active` and give it a higher `z-index` than 2. Maybe something like this: `.sy-active { z-index: 9 !important; }`. The `!important` may not be required.

Answer (score 0):

The issue you are having has to do with the fact that while the opacity is changing on each image, the css display property is not changed to `none`. One of you slides contains a link to the about us page and its z-index is above all the other slides so it is the one that gets clicked even when it's `opacity` is 0.